# Tab Create Event Handler

Tags: javafx, tabs

In my code, `MyTab` extendes `Tab` and until version 8 existed the method `setEventHandler (...);`
As I am now using the javaFX 12 version, this method is `private` and I can not use it anymore.
I also do not have access to the variable `eventHandlerManager` of `Tab`.
How can I access this functionality in JavaFX 12?

Here is an example of the code.

> ```
> public class MyTab extends Tab {
>   ...
>
>   protected ObjectProperty<EventHandler<EventAction>> onEventDockRequest=null;
>
>     public void setOnEventDockRequest(EventHandler<EventAction> value) {
>         onEventDockRequestProperty().set(value);
>     }
>
>     public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<EventAction>> onEventDockRequestProperty() {
>         if (onEventDockRequest == null) {
>             onEventDockRequest = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<EventAction>>() {
>
>                 @Override protected void invalidated() {
>                     setEventHandler(EventAction.DOCK_REQUEST, get());  // here error                 
>                 }
>
>                 @Override public Object getBean() {
>                     return DTab.this;
>                 }
>
>                 @Override public String getName() {
>                     return "onEventDockRequest";
>                 }
>             };
>         }
>         return onEventDockRequest;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: It's going to be the `setOnAction()` method.

Comment: Pardon me @Zephyr, but I can't find method `setOnAction()` for class `javafx.scene.control.Tab`. What am I missing?

Comment: @tretonis, what `Tab` events are you interested in handling?

Comment: @Abra I believe they want to fire and handle a custom made event. They've added event-handler properties to their `Tab` subclass to make handling this custom event easier (same as all the `onXXX` properties of `Node` and its subclasses). Unfortunately, the API necessary to do this appears to have been hidden in recent releases; this is unlike `Node` which exposes a protected `setEventHandler` method.

Comment: @Zephyr OP appears to be trying to add custom properties for handling a custom made event.